# Refreshing URL glitch - cloud updating/rewriting

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, cloud, vba

Hello I've created an VBA script which saves me jpg from excel and then gsync uploads it on gDrive, but here comes the thing. The URL for downloading is volatile and I need full resolution image.

There is [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XnS38fU57wSlBHNm80VzVtNWM/view) so you can open in awful google UI
and I would like to open [THIS](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/8cl0RPSOk8twcnrBUexBWSpaytO451WiqMQhICEZb4T0I6V252_W1RVOpCq_9rcIT0-zqA7ySKQ=w1153-h715) => volatile link :(

Or can I use this VBA to upload image on some other Cloud directly from excel?

Comment: You'll need to explain how you determine the URL to download from. - post the code you have so far. Also, the specific image you linked to has some hate speech in one of the later frames so maybe don't use that one as an example

Comment: SO isn't for asking for site recommendations.

Comment: @barrowc I'm just copy URL from browser and pinning that on some place, so I need stable URL even if I'll edit that picture. (taht second link works like 2 minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id= "ID"
```

If you change URL in view mode you can view that image dirrect.

[There](http://blog.appsevents.com/2014/04/how-to-bypass-google-drive-viewer-and.html) are other files types.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Drive SDK to get the file details including the latest temporary download link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

...or you can make a parent or grandparent folder public and work out a URL direct to the image using its filename, like this:
http://gappstips.com/gmail/use-google-drive-to-host-your-gmail-signature/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XnS38fU57wSlBHNm80VzVtNWM/3.jpg Nah still not get it